# Trouble while duplicating and removing table rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, duplicates, row

I have some trouble while creating and removing dynamically table rows.

In fact the function of creation works fine, and for removing also, but it just works for the first row.

I've done some research and I think it may comes on the fact that the duplicated row are not there when the document is ready.

This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add_row').click(function(){
            var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
            var $clone = $tr.clone();
            $clone.find(':text').val('');
            $tr.after($clone);   ;
        });
        $('.remove_row').click(function(){
            var $that = $(this);
            var whichtr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var $table = $that.parents('table:first');
            alert($that.parents('tr:first').length);
            if ($('tr', $table).length > 1) {
                //on supprime
                whichtr.remove()  
            }else{
                //on fait rien
                alert('Vous ne pouvez pas supprimer la première ligne');
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

For the first rows I can add and remove rows, but for the duplicate rows, when I click on their buttons for removing and duiplicating rows, nothing works.

Here is my table:

```
<tr class="tr_clone">
    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="text" style="width:200px" name="facture[][libelle]"><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="text" style="width:75px" name="facture[][quantite]"><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="text" style="width:100px" name="facture[][prix_unitaire]" ><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="text" style="width:100px" name="facture[][taxes]"><br></td>
    <td style="text-align:right">&nbsp;0,00 € <input type="hidden" name="facture[][prix]"></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="images/add.png" class="add_row"> <img src="images/remove.png" id="do_not_remove" class="remove_row"></td>
</tr>
```

I would like not to remove the last table row, I mean if there is only one, we should not remove.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are installing the click listener only on `document.ready`, so the ones created later don't have the click listener.

try event delegation:

`$("body").on("click", '.add_row', function(){`

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.
>   http://api.jquery.com/on/